# ObjectDisposedException thrown when trying to save files to a DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am uploading a text file and writing each split line to a database. The file has over a million lines. The upload and saving to the database works but breaks after the save on the `await _context.SaveChangesAsync();` line with the following error

> System.ObjectDisposedException HResult=0x80131622 Message=Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances. Object name: 'LanternDBContext'.

```
public async void ImportUploadTextFile(string fileName)
{
    string rootFolder = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(rootFolder + "/UploadedFiles/", fileName)))
    {
        List<UploadTextFile> InputList = new List<UploadTextFile>();

        while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
        {
            string str;
            string[] strArray;
            str = sr.ReadLine();

            strArray = str.Split(' ');
            InputList.Add(new UploadTextFile
            {

                CorpCode = strArray[0],
                AccountCode = strArray[1],
                CostCenter = strArray[2]

            });
        }

        _context.UploadTextFile.AddRange(InputList);


    }
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Comment: problem isn't very much clear.

Comment: What happens if you use SaveChanges (not the Async mode)?

Comment: What if you put `await _context.SaveChangesAsync();` into the `using` block?

Comment: Please show how you inject `_contex` ?

Comment: `ObjectDisposedException` has nothing to do with file sizes. The error complains about `LanternDBContext`. It complains that you tried to use an object that was already disposed. I'd bet the context was used in a `using` block earlier, or it was declared as `Singleton` and manually disposed

Comment: @Steve site continuously tries to load although writing to the database is complete

Comment: @MikeChristensen still receives the same error

Comment: I was getting this error after running localhost for few hours.
Restarting the app solved it.

Answer (score 3):

`async void` is only meant for *event handlers*. It fires off a fire-and-forget task that can't be awaited or monitored and could still be running long after an ASP.NET request terminates and its context gets disposed.

The proper syntax for an asynchronous method that doesn't return anythig is `async Task`. The method signature should change to

```
public async Task ImportUploadTextFile(string fileName)
```

and whoever calls `ImportUploadTextFile` should await it. If it's called in a controller action, the action itself should be asynchronous and await it, eg :

```
public async Task Post(whatever)
{
    ....
    await ImportUploadTextFile(fileName);
}
```

Comment: This is currently how I have it setup. Please explain further if i am mistaken? Also how would i avoid the context getting disposed too early

Comment: @NarianNaidoo Seems I forgot to use the correct signature in the answer though. `ImportUploadTextFile`'s signature should be `async void`, not `async Task`. Change it to `async Task` and then *await* that method. Using `async Task` won't help if you don't await the method.

Comment: @NarianNaidoo **don't** use `async void`. Use `async Task`

Answer (score 1):

Your db context is disposed by the time you trying to save changes. Probably your method

> ImportUploadTextFile

is used out of the proper scope.

Comment: How would open another instance of the db context to avoid this?

Comment: @NarianNaidoo you probably shoud move ImportUploadTextFile call inside using(...){} scope where db context is "alive".