# System.ObjectDisposedException error when saving to local DB in EF Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have this simple code to add a record to the database

```
async Task<Therapist> IAddTherapist.AddTherapist(Therapist therapist)
{
    try
    {
        therapist.TherapistId = Guid.NewGuid();
        await _context.Therapists.AddAsync(therapist);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return therapist;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

When I do this I get this error:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection: Error: An error occurred using the connection to database 'SPK' on server '(local)'.
>
> Exception thrown: 'System.ObjectDisposedException' in
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll
> Exception thrown: 'System.ObjectDisposedException' in SPKAdministration.dll

If I change the `await _context.SaveChangesAsync()` to `_context.SaveChanges()`, the record is saved.

How do you do an `AddAsync` and `SaveChangesAsync()` in the same call like this?

Per the answer below, I have added the constructor for the class

```
private readonly SpkContext _context;

public AddTherapist(SpkContext context)
{
    _context = context;
}
```

Here is the call from the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] Therapist therapist)
{
    var result = _therapist.AddTherapist(therapist);
    return Ok();
}
```

Context is not created anywhere else during this call. There is no dispose method in the class that is killing the context either.

Here is how it is added for dependency injection:

```
 builder.Services
        .AddDbContext<SpkContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("SPKClient")));
```

Comment: Your code is right. Something wrong around this piece of code. Like `async void` or `Task.WhenAll`.

Comment: Yeah, my money's on the method being `async void`.

Comment: It is most probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55143857/objectdisposedexception-thrown-when-trying-to-save-files-to-a-dbcontext where the method signature has `async void`.

Comment: I attached the full signature of the method.  It is not async void.

Comment: Where do you call that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies further up the call stack.

Somewhere, something is creating your `_context`, and somewhere else something is disposing that `_context`. For example, maybe your `_context` is being created by your constructor and disposed by the Dispose method on your class. Or maybe your Dependency Injection framework is creating the _context when the request begins and Disposing it when the request completes.

If the code calling your `AddTherapist` method isn't `await`ing the result (or the code calling *that* method isn't awaiting *its* result, and so on), you can end up in a situation where Dispose gets called before `SaveChangesAsync()` is done with its work. That's what's causing this exception.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:  I forgot to put the await keyword on the call from the controller on the POST.  Once I awaited the method call it worked.  Thank you @StriplingWarrior for the clues.